# Page refreshes whenever I click on the text area, doesn't allow me to fill in any text

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to create a page that will automatically update inputted text in a database. However, whenever I click on the textarea the page seems to automatically refresh. If I type quick enough, some text will go through and be updated. Not sure what the error could be, am also using twitter bootstrap if that is enlightening at all, will give the rest of the code if needed. Here's what seems to be the relevant part of my code:

```
    <div class="container contentContainer" id="topContainer">

  <div class="row">

    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3" id="topRow">

      <textarea class="form-control mytext" name="thought" placeholder="Where can we help your business go?"></textarea>

    </div>

  </div>

</div>

<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(".contentContainer").css("min-height",$(window).height());
    $("textarea").css("height",$(window).height()-0.64*$(window).height());

</script>
```

edit: removed keyup function.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem — http://jsbin.com/notuxenene/edit?html,output — it must be caused by something other than the code you shared with us. Please run your reduced test cases to make sure they actually reproduce the problem. http://sscce.org/ should be useful reading.

Comment: Your code it's quite weird, do you really need to post any letter???

Comment: @Vixed, honestly just learning from tutorials. Always open to learning something new if you have a suggestion!

Answer (score 2):

Instead of keyup event you should use blur event to post data to server.

```
$("textarea").blur(function() {
  $.post("updatethought.php", {thought:$("textarea").val()});
});
```

Comment: **blur** will send the post also after a mouse click or a tap event.

Answer (score 1):

@bpr Do you realize you re using a keyup event here:

```
 $("textarea").keyup(function() {
      $.post("updatethought.php", {thought:$("textarea").val()});
    });
```

You are saying:
If I hit any key than post it!!

You need to do this in an other way, an option will be using 'blur' instead.

Comment: The textarea will refresh without the keyup function in place, I must be missing something else.

Comment: If Your  keyup function is not in your HTML, please remove it from your code, so you can update your question. You need to post here the current code you are using, so please do. I also regret a little that you up voted the other answer which is telling you the same I did. But is your free choice. We respect always that.

Answer (score 1):

I used **get** because is faster than post if you need it just to get a list of element for suggestions.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $('.contentContainer').css('min-height',$(window).height());
        $('textarea').css('height',$(window).height()-0.64*$(window).height());
        $('textarea[name="thought"]').unbind(); //to be sure that aren't other triggers
        $('textarea[name="thought"]').on('keyup',function(e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          $.get('updatethought.php', {thought:$('textarea').val()});
        });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use **blur** event to update data into db;
On blur of any input field of your form do data validation of each input field, on validation success do ajax call to update your data in db. In this way your page will not refresh while entering data into form.

```
$("textarea").blur(function() {
   updateDB();
});

$("input").blur(function() {
   updateDB();
});


function updateDB(){
   // do data validation
   // on data validation success do ajax

}
```

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ajax_get_post.asp

Comment: Thanks this looks useful, could you point me to a source I should look at for the ajax functions to be used?

Comment: sure, I hv updated my ans with a link for your reference.

Comment: Thank you! Much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Sorry everyone, turns out I failed to close an href in an earlier part of my code and that caused it to think the entire page was a link. All of the function suggestions were very helpful and informative though, thanks!